# Only last React element rendered inside for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple function that takes an infinite number of strings, and renders Comment components. However, only the last component is rendered here. Here's the function:

```
function renderComments(...comments) {
    for(let i = 0; i<comments.length; i++) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Comment/>, document.getElementById('comments')).setState({name: comments[i]});
    }
}
```

Here's the Comment component:

```
class Comment extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: 'default'
        };
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div> 

            {this.state.name}.

            </div>  
        );
    }
}
```

And here I'm calling the function:

```
renderComments('hi', 'hello', 'whatever');
```

Sorry if this is a noob question, I just got into React.

Comment: You're repeatedly rendering into the element with ID `comments`, each one overwriting the last. Perhaps what you want is a `CommentList` component?

Comment: [`ReactDOM.render()` controls the contents of the container node you pass in. Any existing DOM elements inside are replaced when first called. Later calls use React’s DOM diffing algorithm for efficient updates.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert with React, but looks your code is rendering the `Comment` component inside the same HTML container.

So each loop run the render replace the HTML container with the new `Comment`.

You should create a render method that handle your list.

I found here some guide for you:

http://jasonjl.me/blog/2015/04/18/rendering-list-of-elements-in-react-with-jsx/

Hope this helps.